# Why is dask returning none on a CUDA function?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to layer dask on top of my cuda functions, but when dask returns I get a  NoneType object.

```py
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


@cuda.jit()
def addingNumbersCUDA (big_array, big_array2, save_array):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < big_array.shape[0]:
        for j in range (big_array.shape[1]):
            save_array[i][j] = big_array[i][j] * big_array2[i][j]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    client = Client(cluster)


    big_array = np.random.random_sample((100, 3000))
    big_array2  = np.random.random_sample((100, 3000))
    save_array = np.zeros(shape=(100, 3000))


    arraysize = 100
    threadsperblock = 64
    blockspergrid = (arraysize + (threadsperblock - 1))

    x = client.submit(addingNumbersCUDA[blockspergrid, threadsperblock], big_array, big_array2, save_array)


    y = client.gather(x)
    print(y)
```

I understand that you don't actually return in a cuda function and that the results are pushed back to the array you called in. Is this why I'm getting a noneType, or is it because I'm using dask wrong for cuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in this question: [How to use Dask to run python code on the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194625/how-to-use-dask-to-run-python-code-on-the-gpu) by Matthew Rocklin, dask can't handle in-place operations. In order to account for this it would be better to add an additional function that handles the gpu code.

```py
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster


@cuda.jit()
def addingNumbersCUDA (big_array, big_array2, save_array):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < big_array.shape[0]:
        for j in range (big_array.shape[1]):
            save_array[i][j] = big_array[i][j] * big_array2[i][j]

def toCUDA (big_array, big_array2, save_array):
    arraysize = 100
    threadsperblock = 64
    blockspergrid = (arraysize + (threadsperblock - 1))

    d_big_array = cuda.to_device(big_array)
    d_big_array2 = cuda.to_device(big_array2)
    d_save_array = cuda.to_device(save_array)

    addingNumbersCUDA[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_big_array, d_big_array2, d_save_array)

    save_array = d_save_array.copy_to_host()
    return save_array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = LocalCluster()
    client = Client(cluster)

    big_array = np.random.random_sample((100, 3000))
    big_array2  = np.random.random_sample((100, 3000))
    save_array = np.zeros(shape=(100, 3000))

    x = client.submit(toCUDA, big_array, big_array2, save_array)


    y = client.gather(x)
    print(y)
```